# MeteorJS: Input value in a table is displayed twice

Tags: javascript, html, web, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have this issue with MeteorJS with regards to inserting value to an editable table. Whenever I insert a value and the blur event handler is called (doing an update operation to db), the value in the table cell is displayed twice.

I have the code available at: https://github.com/jeffrey-effendy/sudolver

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced something similar with contenteditable fields. Think its caused because the value stays in the cell but the {{value}} also adds a value, so its displaying twice.

You can fix it by clearing the cell first:

```
Template.createCell.events({
    "blur .cell": function(e) {
       var val = $(e.currentTarget).text();
       $(e.currentTarget).text('');
       Meteor.call("update", this._id, val);
    }
});
```

Comment: Aaah yes. You could even use a helper on the cell instead of directly using `{{value}}` to make it smoother: clear the contents only when `value` is defined, then return the value.

Answer (score 0):

What is `event` in your `createCell` event function? Seems you don't have it defined in the event's arguments:

```
  Template.createCell.events({
    "blur .cell": function(event) { // here
      Meteor.call("update", this._id, event.target.innerHTML);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I was assuming event is a global variable when an event is called (since it works with an without). In any case, it still does not solve the issue of duplication.